# How to save a very big Java object using Kryo into Blob in Oracle and avoid KryoException Buffer overflow?

Tags: java, serialization, oracle11g, blob, kryo

I am trying to save a very big object using Kryo,

```
public static byte[] toBytes(KryoPool kryoPool, Object object) {
    try (Output output = new Output(32768, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8)) {
        kryoPool.run(kryo -> {
            kryo.setReferences(false);
            kryo.writeObject(output, object);
            return null;
        });
        return output.toBytes();
    }
}
```

and I get exception:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 1
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:167)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeByte(Output.java:225)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:623)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:557)
```

This array of bytes should be then saved into Oracle table, Blob field.
I now realize two things:

1. byte[] is limited in size, can not be bigger than 2^31-1? how should I deal with very big objects that are bigger than the size of max. byte array?
2. How to avoid Kryo Buffer overflow exception?

UPDATE: 
Thanks a lot. I am just wondering at which point I should call Kryo serialization:

```
    try (final PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DATA_STORAGE (ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)")) 
{
        final Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
        OutputStream out = blob.setBinaryStream(0L);

        Output output = new Output(out);

        pstmt.setInt(1, id);
        pstmt.setBlob(2, blob);

        //probably here?   
        kryoPool.run(kryo -> {
            kryo.setReferences(false);
            kryo.writeObject(output, object);
            return null;
        });

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create an intermediate `byte[]`, but stream direct to the BLOB:

```
try (Output output = new Output(blob.setBinaryStream(0L))) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am just wondering at which point I should call Kryo serialization: